# Google ReCaptcha hide sign

Tags: wordpress, recaptcha

I have a minor issue with "contact form 7"

Protected by reCAPTCHA sign - http://prntscr.com/kossrn , is there any way to hide it?

I use this plugin for reCAPTCHA - http://prntscr.com/kossyw

Comment: for a quick solution try to add CSS, If you can share url, I can help you in identifying class and id to apply style.

Comment: @Robin , sounds really great, thank you a lot!

Here's the link: https://www.brandnames.net/